react-native-community/cli error when using custom template
I'm trying to use my React Native boilerplate using the CLI but every time I try it shows me this error. I don't know what I need to fix here. It works if I use the react-native@latest init but it will be deprecated.  I want to use the react-native-community/cli@latest init.
npx react-native-community/cli@latest init MyApp --template file:///E:/React%20Native/rnboilerplate
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall open
npm error path E:\React Native\RNTesting\react-native-community\cli@latest\package.json
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\React Native\RNTesting\react-native-community\cli@latest\package.json'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-20T03_37_29_814Z-debug-0.log


I re-read the docs of the react-native-community/cli, in the README
react-native-community/cli
to start its npx @react-native-community/cli@latest init MyApp but in the react-native-community/cli/commands there is no "@" in the beginning of the commands

npx react-native-community/cli@latest init MyApp

but still my problem with using the local repo E://React Native/RNTesting/ is not working, I worked it around using the GitHub repo.
